# Is it possible to create a "Rectangle is a Square but a Square is not a Rectangle" type?

Tags: typescript, nominal-typing

I'm attempting to create a "loose" nominal type that allows assignment from its base type, but not from other nominal types that have that base type.

There excellent `Nominal` type [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202#issuecomment-1502791106):

```
declare const nominalSymbol: unique symbol;
export type Nominal<T extends string, U> = U & { [nominalSymbol]: T };
```

but is there a way to expand on this to functionally do

```
export type LooseNominal<T extends string, U> = Nominal<T, U> | U; // but prohibit direct assignment of nominal types derived from U
```

Example of desired behavior:

```
type Address = LooseNominal<'Address', string>;
type FirstName = LooseNominal<'FirstName', string>;

let address: Address = "123 Some St";
let firstName: FirstName = "John";
address = "456 Another St"; // no problem
address = firstName; // Type Error!
```

As far as I know, there's no way to do a constraint like `U !extends Nominal<any, any>`. I tried `U extends Nominal<T, any> ? never : U`, but apparently you can't use a ternary clause there, and trying to put it on the other side of the `=` ends up in type simplification that prevents it from working as a nominal type at all.

Comment: If that level of specificity is important in your program (primitive discrimination via branding), I think it's probably acceptable to pay the insignificant runtime cost of deriving the types via identity function calls ([example](https://tsplay.dev/N7VyDw))... or just directly [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) if total runtime elision is mandatory. IMO it's an anti-pattern to allow assignment of an unbranded variant when you're discriminating between branded primitives. (Not my downvote, btw.)

Comment: @jsejcksn that's an interesting solution (didn't realize you could do stuff like that!), but $Foo(value) isn't really much more succinct than `value as Foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need assignability but not cross-assignability, use optional branding:

```
declare const brand: unique sympol
type Brand<T, F> = T & {[brand]?: F}
//                             ^
```

Comment: This solution is *almost* perfect, but there's an edge case where it doesn't behave quite as desired. See [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/mb3b2W)

Comment: also, nit: `sympol` has typo